# How to handle a webview confirm dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, webview, popup, handle

I'm displaying a webpage in a WebView and on the webpage, there is a button.  When you click the button, a confirmation dialog is supposed to popup, but it doesn't show in my WebView.  It does popup if I go to the same webpage in the android browser.  Anyone know how to handle popup dialogs coming from a webpage inside your WebView?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Ok, found the answer and here it is!

In order to handle a popup confirmation coming from a webpage in your WebView, you need to override the onJsConfirm method in WebChromeClient to display the popup as an Android Alert dialog.  Here is the code to do so.

```
final Context myApp = this; 
final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    @Override
    public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(myApp)
        .setTitle("App Titler")
        .setMessage(message)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                result.confirm();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                result.cancel();
            }
        })
        .create()
        .show();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to set your WebChromeClient in your WebView...

```
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
```

Note.. this isn't my code, but I found it and it works perfectly for handling javascript confirmation dialogs in a WebView!

Cheers!

Comment: I have mvc view and <a href="javascript:;" onclick="Logout_Confirm()" id="SignOut">Sign Out</a> but not working on android emulator. I need help in this,

Comment: Thanks brockoli ... After a bit of experimentation it seems that it is enough to just return false from the onJsConfirm method to have the WebView display a dialog for you - at least in JellyBean ... The default WebChromeClient already returns false, so `webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());` did the job for me!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Brockoli for the method. 
I needed this for Xamarin.Android

```
 public class MyWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
{
    private Context mContext;
    private JsResult res;

    public MyWebChromeClient(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }


     public override bool OnJsConfirm(WebView view, string url, string message, JsResult result)
    {

        res = result;

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.SetTitle("Confirm:");
        builder.SetMessage(message);
        builder.SetPositiveButton(Android.Resource.String.Ok,  OkAction);
        builder.SetNegativeButton(Android.Resource.String.Cancel, CancelAction);
        builder.Create();
        builder.Show();

        return true;


        //return base.OnJsConfirm(view, url, message, result);
    }

    private void CancelAction(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
    {
        res.Cancel();
    }

    private void OkAction(object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e)
    {
        res.Confirm();
    }
}
```

This back in the activity where webview is created (web_view)

```
web_view.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

Worth mentioning that I found a problem with this when the user dismisses the dialog box by clicking outside of it.  The browser keeps waiting until it has a result, which (now the dialog box has gone) never happens.  This results in the browser effectively locking up.  To solve it, I added this:

```
.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        result.cancel();
    }
})
```

Hope that helps someone!