# how to display popup in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using the below code to open URL in in webview of my application.
But webview in my application not opening pop-up in my application.

If I try to open the same URL in my phone native browser its displaying pop up window.

My Layout file:

```
       <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

My Java File.

```
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Please let me know what changes I need to do in my app so that It behave same as native browser.

Comment: Have you tried after enabling Java-script ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that also . Updated the question.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726377/how-to-handle-a-webview-confirm-dialog)