# Prompt, Alert and confirm JavaScript inside a Android WebView not found

Tags: javascript, android, android-fragments, webview, webchromeclient

I'm writing an application on android that shows a transmition from an Ip Camera, this camarea is a D-Link, for see the transmission I go to the ip: `192.168.1.4/MJPEG.CGI?.mjpeg` and it works in my navigator, but to access it asks me for an account for the admin compound by a Javascript Prompt:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzafE.png)

In My android application I'm using a Navigation Drawable with fragments and I have designated an fragment for the transmition, I'm using a WebView, XML of my fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.promindsoft.theprodigyeye.MainFragment">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="Enter Text"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textColorHighlight="#ff7eff15"
        android:textColorHint="#f23012"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/human_greeting"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

It's very simple, my button is to load the url it is allowed into my EditText, into my MainFragment.java:

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    Button b1;
    EditText ed1;

    private WebView mWebView ;

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        b1=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        ed1=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ed1.setText("http://192.168.1.76/javas.html");

        mWebView =(WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webView);


        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Okey",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                String url = ed1.getText().toString();

                WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
                webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
                webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
                webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

                mWebView.loadUrl(url);
                mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
            }
        });
        return view;

    }



    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient  {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
        {
            webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

                private View mCustomView;

               @Override
                public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
                   AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                           .setTitle(view.getTitle())
                           .setMessage(message)
                           .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                   result.confirm();
                               }
                           })
                           .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               @Override
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                   result.cancel();
                               }
                           });

                   b.show();

                   // Indicate that we're handling this manually
                   return true;
               }
                @Override
                public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result)
                {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext()).setMessage(message).setCancelable(true).show();
                    result.confirm();
                    return true;
                }
                @Override
                public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)
                {
                    // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
                    if (mCustomView != null)
                    {
                        callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                        return;
                    }

                }


            });

            webview.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }


    }

}
```

I've been doing test with anothers Js files to try to get Alerts or Confirm Alerts but I can't get it.

JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //document.write("Shit")
            alert("Hola")


   var x;
    if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
        x = "You pressed OK!";
    } else {
        x = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
    document.write(x);


     var person = prompt("Please enter your name");

    if (person != null) {
        document.write("Hello " + person + "! How are you today?");
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Okey</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

for the example with an Alert Desition I tried with onJsConfirm but nothing happened, and less with the page that give me the transmition, ever taken a negative answer about the login:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RDro.png)

I need really help, I've looking around a lot of pages and videos to find the way to do it, but I dont have answer. Please someone can help me?

Comment: [confirm in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2726377/6521116)  and  [alert in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5271898/6521116)

Answer (score 0):

Set your mWebView's `WebChromeClient` just flowed it's initiation, **NOT** in method:`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`

Here is the codes:

```
....

b1=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
ed1=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
ed1.setText("http://192.168.1.76/javas.html");

mWebView =(WebView)view.findViewById(R.id.webView);

// ***** PUT YOUR CODE HERE! *****
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {...}
```